# When I run this it outputs 0 for the value "sm"

Tags: python

```
print("Please input your values")

strength = input("STRENGTH: ")
dexterity = input ("DEXTERITY: ")
constitution = input("CONSTITUTION: ")
intellegence = input("INTELLEGENCE: ")
wisdom = input("WISDOM: ")
charisma = input("CHARISMA: ")
sm = 0
dxm = 0
cm = 0
im = 0
wm = 0
chm = 0

if strength == 1:
    sm = -5
    return sm
elif strength == 2 or strength == 3:
    sm = -4
    return sm
elif strength == 4 or strength == 5:
    sm = -3
    return sm
elif strength == 6 or strength == 7:
    sm = -2
    return sm
elif strength == 8 or strength == 9:
    sm = -1
    return sm
elif strength == 10 or strength == 11:
    sm = +0
    return sm
elif strength == 12 or strength == 13:
    sm = +1
    return sm
elif strength == 14 or strength == 15:
    sm = +2
    return sm
elif strength == 16 or strength == 17:
    sm = +3
    return sm
elif strength == 18 or strength == 19:
    sm = +4
    return sm
elif strength == 20 or strength == 21:
    sm = +5
    return sm
elif strength == 22 or strength == 23:
    sm = +6
    return sm
elif strength == 24 or strength == 25:
    sm = +7
    return sm
elif strength == 26 or strength == 27:
    sm = +8
    return sm
elif strength == 28 or strength == 29:
    sm = +9
    return sm
elif strength == 30:
    sm = +10
    return sm

print(str(sm))
```

I am not sure why the code outputs 0 on the value sm when I print it. I have tried many things, including indenting the if, elif, elif, elif... code in a *def modify(value, modifier):* and that unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: your inputs are strings and your are comparing with numeric values, the equalities are always false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` returns a string. If you type 1 the value of `strength` will become `"1"` which is not equal to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like

```
print("Please input your values")

strength = int(input("STRENGTH: "))

sm = 0
dxm = 0
cm = 0
im = 0
wm = 0
chm = 0

if strength == 1:
    sm -= 5

elif strength == 2 or strength == 3:
    sm -= 4

elif strength == 4 or strength == 5:
    sm -= 3

elif strength == 6 or strength == 7:
    sm -= 2

elif strength == 8 or strength == 9:
    sm -= 1

elif strength == 10 or strength == 11:
    sm += 0

elif strength == 12 or strength == 13:
    sm += 1

elif strength == 14 or strength == 15:
    sm += 2

elif strength == 16 or strength == 17:
    sm += 3

elif strength == 18 or strength == 19:
    sm += 4

elif strength == 20 or strength == 21:
    sm += 5

elif strength == 22 or strength == 23:
    sm += 6

elif strength == 24 or strength == 25:
    sm += 7

elif strength == 26 or strength == 27:
    sm += 8

elif strength == 28 or strength == 29:
    sm += 9

elif strength == 30:
    sm += 10

print(str(sm))
```

The problems that you had in the uploaded code was 
1) you stored in strength input that was `str` that later on, you compared it with int `strength == 1` so it needed to be cast to `int`.
2) the increasing and decreasing was `= +` and `= -` that needed to be `+= and -=`.
3) the return of sm is not necessary since you wanted to print it in the end and not to return value from a function.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are strings and your are comparing with numeric values, the equalities are always false.

Try `strength == '1'` for example